# How render an AngularJS template held in a variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templating

I have an AngularJS template held in a variable as a string, eg:

```
var templateContent = '<h1>{{ title }}</h1><p>{{ intro }}</p>';
```

For reference, this string has been returned from an external API (hence it being held in a variable, rather than a physical file).

How would I go about rendering this template, using Angular's templating engine, and properly binding the expressions like `{{ title }}` and `{{ intro }}`?

Answer (score 0):

[Compile  and Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it with your scope:

```
var templateContent = '<h1>{{ title }}</h1><p>{{ intro }}</p>';
$scope.title = 'test title';
$scope.intro = 'test intro';

var compiledAndLinked = $compile(templateContent)($scope);
```

**Edit:**
Here's and example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div direct>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('direct', function($compile){
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<div>\
                  <input type="text" ng-model="inputHtml" />\
                  <button ng-click="createHtmlInputText()">Create Sample Html</button>\
                  <br/>\
                  <button ng-click="generateHtml()">Generate Html And Append</button>\
                </div>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
          scope.title = 'test title'
          scope.generateHtml = function(){
                var compiled = $compile('<br/>' + scope.inputHtml)(scope);
                element.append(compiled);
          }
          scope.createHtmlInputText = function(){
              scope.inputHtml = '<span style="color:red">{{title}}</span>';
          }
      } 
  };
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/084ejfoc/)**

Comment: Thanks Amir - and what would be your suggestion for how to add `compiledAndLinked` to the DOM/page?

Comment: I've added an example only now(with an edit). Sorry I didn't do this before - I had no time..

Answer (score 0):

this could work, maybe...

```
var templateContent = '<h1>{{ title }}</h1><p>{{ intro }}</p>';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', templateContent);
});
```

....

```
<div ng-include src=" 'templateId.html' "></div>
```

....
I might have use ng-include above wrongly, see docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

**updated**
I got curious, so made a plunkr. here

http://plnkr.co/edit/xApbUzlCQkMXlI4zmFBm?p=preview

it's working =)

```
<h4>first</h4>
<div ng-include src=" 'cached.html' "></div>

<br/>

<h4>second</h4>
<div ng-include=" 'cached.html' "></div>
```